# Importing variable from another file changes it

Tags: python, variables, import, file-writing

I have code where I import variables from another file. In the code I change the variables, and then at the end I write them into the other file where they came from. The way I run this code is from a parent program. My problem arises when I run the parent program, go into this code, change the variables, back out to the parent program, then go back in. When I do this, the variables go back to what they were before I changed them. I have tried to find when this reversion occurs and I am fairly certain it occurs when I import the variables. I put a print(open("file.py").read) before the import and the variables are fine, but afterwards they are altered. I am really not sure why this is happening, especially because I have another program which does something very very similar and it works fine. I tried adding f.flush() after altering the code and it doesn't work.

The parent program (menu.py):

```
while True:
    print()
    print("----------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Menu:")
    print()
    print("Enter 1 to quiz yourself")
    print()
    print("Enter 2 to alter or look up a pair")
    print()
    print("Enter 3 to input solving data")
    print()
    print("Enter . to quit")

    while True:
        choice = input()

        if choice in ["1", "2", "3", "."]:
            break

        else:
            print("Enter 1, 2, 3, or .")

    if choice == "1":
        print()
        print("----------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Quiz:")
        print()
        exec(open("quiz.py").read())

    elif choice == "2":
        print()
        print("----------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Pairs:")
        print()
        exec(open("pairs.py").read())

    elif choice == "3":
        print()
        print("----------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Input Data:")
        print()
        exec(open("input_data.py").read())

    elif choice == ".":
        break
```

The main file where my problem is occuring (input_data.py):

```
print(open("accuracy.py").read())

from accuracy import attempts, DNF, solves, current_streak, longest_streak

print(open("accuracy.py").read())

print("Press . to go back to menu")


while True:
    print()
    print("Attempts: ", attempts)
    print("DNFs: ", DNF)
    print("Solves: ", solves)
    print("Accuracy: {}".format( 100 * solves / attempts))
    print("Current Streak: ", current_streak)
    print("Longest Streak: ", longest_streak)
    print()


    print("Did you solve it?")
    foo = input("Yes or No: ").upper()

    if foo == "YES":
        print(":(")
        DNF += 1
        attempts += 1

        current_streak = 0


    elif foo == "NO":
        print(":)")
        solves += 1
        attempts += 1

        current_streak += 1

        if current_streak > longest_streak:
            longest_streak = current_streak


    elif foo == ".":
        break


# For some reason this writing is not happening if I do not end menu.py
# For instance, if I were to start menu, then go into input_data and enter data, then back out into menu, and then go
# back into input_data, the data would be the same as it was at the very beginning of this example.

with open("accuracy.py", "w") as f:
    f.write("attempts = {}\nDNF = {}\nsolves = {}\ncurrent_streak = {}\nlongest_streak = {}".format(attempts, DNF, solves, current_streak, longest_streak))
    f.flush()
```

The file I am importing variables from (accuracy.py):

```
attempts = 251
DNF = 104
solves = 147
current_streak = 0
longest_streak = 9
```

Comment: Are you trying to import from `accuracy.py` multiple times in the same run? Python caches its imports and won't reread a file once it has imported it once.

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to switch from menu.py to input_data.py, change stuff, go back to menu.py and then back to input_data.py, and the file has kept its changes.